# Why We are using javascript in server-side?

Tags: server-side, serverside-javascript, server-side-scripting

Why we started using javascript in server-side ?? and which is the best javascript language for server-side ?? and why for e.g node.js

Comment: This is a too-broad question as it's a primarily opinion-based question. I recommend you to read on Google about the different JS frameworks for backend / server-side and then make your own conclusions. But questions like this one might get closed (and deleted) in this site.

Answer (score 1):

By using both client and server ***JavaScript***, you can reduce the number of different concepts required for web development, get a possibility to reuse code between client and server and reduce the need for context switching.

***Node.js*** uses an event-oriented architecture, which integrates very well with ***JavaScript*** (callbacks!). Using an event loop, Node interprets requests in a single thread asynchronously rather than sequentially, not allowing locks. This makes it incredibly fast, perfect for handling a very high number of requests, one of the main advantages that has excited so many developers to explore this technology.